# How to transform Clojure map with collections as vals to seq of maps?

Tags: clojure

I have a map where each key has a collection as value:

```
{:name ["Wut1" "Wut2"] :desc ["But1" "But2"]}
```

The value collections can be assumed to have the same number of elements.

How to transform it into a list (or vector) where each element is a map with key being the key from original collection and value being 1 value like:

```
[{:name "Wut1" :desc "But1"} {:name "Wut2" :desc "But2"}]
```

It should be said that the number of keys is not known before (so I can't hardcode for `:name` and `:desc`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule `apply map vector` will always do a transpose operation:

```
(apply map vector '(["Wut1" "Wut2"] ["But1" "But2"]))
;;=> (["Wut1" "But1"] ["Wut2" "But2"])
```

With that one *trick* in hand, we just need to make sure to `zipmap` each *vector object* (e.g. `["Wut1" "But1"]`) with the keys:

```
(fn [m]
  (->> m
       vals
       (apply map vector)
       (map #(zipmap (keys m) %))))
;;=> ({:name "Wut1", :desc "But1"} {:name "Wut2", :desc "But2"})
```

Another rule to go by is that there's a problem when you have consecutive `map`s - really you ought to bring together the *map functions*, rather than needlessly transferring items from list to list. (This can often be done using `comp`). See @amalloy's solution for how to avoid *double mapping*. Also of course the `keys` function call should not be done repeatedly as here.

Answer (score 6):

```
(fn [m]
  (let [ks (keys m)]
    (apply map (fn [& attrs]
                 (zipmap ks attrs))
           (vals m))))
```

1. Get the list of keys to use to label everything with
2. Use `apply map` to "transpose" the list-of-lists in `(vals m)` from "for each attribute, a list of the values it should have" to "for each object, a list of the attributes it should have".
3. `zipmap` that back together with the keys extracted in the first part.